# Extract subtype from object

Tags: typescript

Is it NOWADAYS possible to extract only a subset of properties at runtime. Probably using some fancy decorators or metadata library?

```
function only<IN extends OUT, OUT>(object: IN): OUT {
  const result: OUT = {};
  for (const key of getKeysOf<OUT>()) {
    result[key] = object[key];
  }
  return result;
}
```

How could one write such a function `getKeysOf`?

Example:

```
interface Foo {
  x: string;
}

interface Bar extends Foo {
  y: string;
}

const foo = only<Bar, Foo>({x: 'x', y: 'y'});

// foo should contain ONLY properties of `Foo`, not `Bar`
// -> foo == {'x'} should hold
```

Comment: You are not allowed to use `for (const key of OUT)` because `OUT` is a type - not a value.

Comment: I know, this was just figurative

Comment: Please provide reproducable example. I mean `getKeysOf`

Comment: Using of `OUT` generic in `getKeysOf<OUT>()` can't affect runtime code

Comment: Can you provide an input and expected output, struggling to understand what the issue is? Are you looking for something like [pick](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick) from Lodash?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have to dive too deeply into Typescript, but we could achieve something pretty similar to what you're asking by simply using classes:

```html
class Foo {
    x: string = '';
}

class Bar implements Foo {
    x: string = '';
    y: string = '';
}

class Baz {
    z: string = '';
}

function only<T, K extends T>(a: T, b: K): T {
    for (let key in a) {
        a[key] = b[key]
    }
    return a
}

const foo = only(new Foo(), new Bar()); // works
const fooToo = only(new Baz(), new Bar()); // errors out
```

The above should work for plain objects as well, provided they have similar keys.

It's important to remember that types are stripped out at runtime, so we cannot simply use `OUT` in `<IN extends OUT, OUT>`. We actually have to provide `OUT` as something Javascript can interact with.

Comment: I understand your approach: You basically just use a "template object" to have access to "metadata" about the properties that exist. But that requires classes and can't work on interfaces.

Comment: That's 100% correct. If you're looking to try use interfaces at runtime, you're out of luck. As mentioned above, interfaces are stripped out when Typescript is transpiled to Javascript, and that's not likely to change - probably ever. Your only real option is classes.

Comment: I found a bunch of compiler-plugins that help to do reflection at runtime, but they require to adjust the tooling to use them, e.g. https://github.com/edbentley/ts-validate-type